# Could an 11 1/2 year old publish a book?

Tags: fiction, young-author

I am working on a good story. (I will not tell more about it because I do not want my idea stolen.) I am only 11 years old. Could I possibly get it published? if so, how? My dad said that there is no age rule when publishing a book, but I am not quite so sure about that. Also, I do not know if I am ready to publish a book.

Comment: Hi, I hope the linked question helps you out. You may want to browse other questions in the [young author](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-author) tag too. However, since you are so young, you cannot have an account yet. Depending on where you live you need to be 13 or 16 years old.

Comment: Wikipedia has a whole list of books written by children and teenagers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_books_written_by_children_or_teenagers The youngest mentioned there was 9 (as co-writer of an 11-year-old).

Comment: As a general rule, publishing companies publish books, and authors write books.  Thus you are more likely to write a book than to publish it, at any age.  (Some writers self publish their books).  But there have been books published when their writers were a little older than you, and even younger than you, so it is possible fo ryou to get a book published.